# SQL Server Get Custom Column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get get value of column1 at same time?
Example code is :

```
select (2+2) As Column1 , (column1-1) As Column2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select column1, (column1-1) As Column2 
 from (
           select (2+2) As Column1 
 ) t
```

OR

```
select (2+2) As Column1 , (2 + 2 -1) As Column2
```

Comment: @ShaahinRoshan: Can you post your table schema from where you want to pull this information, I generally prefer creating a temporary table with computed column to handle such tasks.

Comment: @EdGibbs : by mistake I have post on answer panel.

Comment: @ShaahinRoshan: I just rejected the changes, you can edit your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79212/discussion-between-shaahin-roshan-and-shantanu-gupta).

Comment: Shaahin: given your situation I'd recommend using the first of Shanatu's examples, or I'd take the query you had in Shanatu's answer, make it into a view, and select from the view. If your calculated columns were as simple as the ones in the original question, a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/ms188300.aspx) would work nicely, but since they're aggregated values then a subquery (Shanatu's first example) or a view will be your best option. Note that a view, while probably the easier option, will probably also be slower.